# Access variable in function within function outside of function?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which registers my iOS device with my APNS server:

```
pushNotification.registerDevice({
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    pw_appid: "***",
    appname: "***"
},

function (status) {
    var deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
},

function (status) {
    console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
});
```

This runs `onLoad`, but I need to access `deviceToken` outside of the scope of `pushNotification.registerDevice() function (status)`.

Is it possible, in this case, to access `deviceToken` which is inside a function within a function, outside of the function?

I thought I could make it a global variable, by using `window.deviceToken`, then calling that later on, but it returns undefined.

Comment: Are you it's not undefined because of the asynchronous nature of the registerDevice function?

Comment: You're right, I was calling it before it was defined.

Comment: Great, I posted an answer addressing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're assigning the token to a global and finding its undefined when you try to use it, you will probably find its because the registerDevice ajax hasn't yet received a response.

Try separating your callback into a separate function, and launch any dependant functions from there.

```
function registerSuccess(status) {
  // Store token globally
  token = status["deviceToken"];
  // or pass as an argument
  // call functions that depend on the token
  Foo(token);
  Bar(); // uses global
}
```

Personally I would try and pass as an argument, save polluting the global namespace.

Answer (score 3):

You could give `deviceToken` a broader scope:

```
var deviceToken;

pushNotification.registerDevice({
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    pw_appid: "***",
    appname: "***"
},

function(status) {
    deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
},

function(status) {
    console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to make `deviceToken` a global variable so it is available in outside scopes by referencing the global scope directly.

```
function (status) {
    window.deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
},
```

If you just want it in a parent scope, not necessarily at the global scope, you can define it in the desired parent scope and then NOT redeclare it in your function:

```
var deviceToken;

pushNotification.registerDevice({
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
    pw_appid: "***",
    appname: "***"
},

function (status) {
    deviceToken = status['deviceToken'];
},

function (status) {
    console.warn('failed to register : ' + JSON.stringify(status));
    navigator.notification.alert(JSON.stringify(['failed to register ', status]));
});
```

Comment: Do I call the variable later by using `window.deviceToken` or `deviceToken`?

Comment: @Charlie - As long as no other scope has declared `deviceToken`, you can reference it with either `window.deviceToken` or `deviceToken`.   `window.deviceToken` forces the global scope, but is not required for reading it's value if there is no other definition of `deviceToken`.

Comment: The global variable ended up working. The problem, as @Aesthete said, was that I was calling it before it wad defined.

Comment: @Charlie: however, you should put that variable just into a higher *parent scope*, putting it into the global scope as ultimate answer is both, bad karma and practice.

Comment: Why is it considered bad practice?

Comment: @Charlie: the *global object* aka *global scope* is shared by any piece of javascript, any code, any library, everything. Imagine everybody would just put any date into it to have it available.. That would end up in trouble, failure and confusion. So its a very good advice to touch that scope pretty much never.